# React component library can not load its own static asset

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, assets

I have a react app (using create react app) and then a component library (using webpack directly). One component in the component library needs to load a png file in one of the components that it exports. In the webpack config for the component library I have a section such as:

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
```

This successfully results in a file like: `29b6b66cf1a691be2b3f.png` in the component libraries output directory. The issue, is that when the *application* uses that component and the component attempts to load the image, the img element is `<img ... src="29b6b66cf1a691be2b3f.png" />` and that fails to load, since that image *actually* lives in the component library folder (within the react application's `node_modules/component-library/` at that point).

I have scoured the internet to the best of my ability, and can not seem to figure out what the best solution would be here. Any help is appreciated. I will quickly offer clarification if needed.

**UPDATE:** I have discovered [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) but it is quite unfortunate that this would require me to eject the "parent" application from create react app. Something I would very much prefer to avoid.

**UPDATE2:** Current plan is to try following something like what is explained [here](https://marmelab.com/blog/2021/07/22/cra-webpack-no-eject.html). The jist of it is to utilize something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to avoid needing to eject and still be able to edit the webpack config via something like:

```
// in ./build.js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
const config = defaults.__get__('config');

// edit webpack config values here
```

... I will answer my own question here if I find that this approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, well this felt like it was much messier than it needed to be, but I was able to figure out a way to accomplish this. The pieces were as follows.

First, needed to install `copy-webpack-plugin`. This was not as simple as it might sound, because I needed to find one that would not conflict with the version of webpack required by my `react-scripts` (create react app). I determined that `copy-webpack-plugin@6.4.1` was the last version to support webpack v4, so I installed that and then added the following to my `package.json`:

```
  "overrides": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": {
      "webpack": "4.44.2"
    }
  },
```

this ensured that it would use the version of webpack that my `react-scripts` installation was expecting.

Then, I also needed to install `rewire`, and add the following to a file called `build.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
const config = defaults.__get__('config');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");


const patterns = [
  { 
    context: "node_modules/component-library/path/",
    from: "*.png", 
    to: "." 
  },
]


if(config.plugins === undefined){
  config.plugins = [new CopyPlugin({patterns})]
}else{
  config.plugins.push(new CopyPlugin({patterns}))
}

// below lets it work in dev mode too
if(config.devServer === undefined){
  config.devServer = {
    writeToDisk: true
  }
}else{
  config.devServer.writeToDisk = true;
}
```

Finally, had to update my build script to be:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "node ./build.js",
    ...
  },
```